# Heroku Django Postgres CREATE postgres schema on database. Multitenancy

Tags: django, postgresql, schema

the docs are not clear. Is it possible to create a schema system on postgres database in order to use postgres schemas as isolated data collection for a multi-tenant app directed by a sub-domain request.